# Allow only root and domain group to login on Linux server

Tags: active-directory, authentication

I have successfully installed PBIS-open to authenticate against active directory. I also used the `/opt/pbis/bin/config RequireMembershipOf` command to allow a certain domain group to login.

I would now like to allow root, and the group(s) specified with the `/opt/pbis/bin/config RequireMembershipOf` command, and deny all other local users to login. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: use Allowuser in /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Comment: I also want to make sure only these users are allowed to logon directly on the server, so "Allowuser" is not an option in this case

Comment: please when you talk about login, please tell how? ssh or console?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm talking about the console

Comment: For your case, you can use pam_access and configure the file /etc/security/access.conf

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try. Just out of curiosity, how do I allow a domain group to the sshd_config? I just tried it but it does not seem to work.

Comment: I'm using AllowGroups in this AllowGroups linuxsysadmins

Comment: I tried that but it wasn't working. What did work in my case was: `AllowGroups DOMAIN\admin`

Comment: Also, the `/etc/security/access.conf`-way is not working. Do you have an example I can try?

Comment: I tried added `- : ALL EXCEPT root : ALL` to `/etc/security/access.conf` just for testing purpose, but it's not working

Comment: but you are using redhat? pam_access modules is include in your pam configuration?

Comment: Yes, I am using RedHat (does it only work on RedHat?). But it's possible it is not included in the pam configuration. How do I check it?

Comment: pam_access works in others distro, but Now I will make an example how to use it in redhat

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use `pam_access` in redhat and centos and so on, first you need to include the module in your pam configura as follow.

```
authconfig --update --enablepamaccess
```

Now you can configure which users that can use your server.

```
/etc/security/access.conf:
```

my example rules

```
+ : DOMAIN\admins : ALL
+ : root : ALL
- : ALL : ALL
```

If you use `DOMAIN\` sintax in front of the users and groups, that would say you are using winbind, for AD join, I'm using pam_ldap with sfu in the windows side, for this reason in my comments I don't use the domain.

Now you have configured Pam for the users access control, but Now you need to be sure that sshd is using pam,

```
grep "UsePAM" /etc/ssh/sshd_config
UsePAM yes
```

If the `UsePAM` isn't yes, you need to change this to yes and restart sshd service

Comment: I can now only login with my root account. The domain group isn't working. I used PBIS-open to join the domain.

Comment: sorry, but I don't see any logs of information about what you are doing, is realy hard to help you in this way, is better with start a chat, we can't continue to write comments.

Comment: Ok, how do we start to chat? I'm kind of new here